# QBO SDK C# - Asynchronously Batch Process Create Multiple Customer

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

i want to insert mulitple customer object i followed this link https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0300_asynchronous_calls/2_batch_process but getting following error  - "You can only add or edit one name at a time.  Please try again."

---

**Posting my code :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web;
using Intuit.Ipp.Core;
using Intuit.Ipp.Security;
using Intuit.Ipp.Services;
using HelloIntuitAnywhere.Utilities;
using Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo;
using Intuit.Ipp.Data.Extensions;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using Intuit.Ipp.Data;

namespace HelloIntuitAnywhere
{
    public partial class BatchRequest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public delegate IntuitBatchResponse DelegateBatchCompleted(IntuitBatchRequest batchRequest);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys.Count > 0)
            {
                String realmId = HttpContext.Current.Session["realm"].ToString();
                String accessToken = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessToken"].ToString();
                String accessTokenSecret = HttpContext.Current.Session["accessTokenSecret"].ToString();
                String consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                String consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                IntuitServicesType intuitServiceType = (IntuitServicesType)HttpContext.Current.Session["intuitServiceType"];

                OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
                ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, realmId, intuitServiceType);
                DataServices commonService = new DataServices(context);

                try
                {
                    switch (intuitServiceType)
                    {
                        case IntuitServicesType.QBO:

                            IntuitBatchRequest batchRequest = new IntuitBatchRequest();
                            batchRequest.BatchItem = new BatchItemRequest[10];

                            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                            {
                                Item itm1 = CreateItem("it8" + i.ToString());
                                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                                guid = guid.Substring(0, 30);
                                guid = i.ToString();
                                BatchItemRequest itm1BatchItem = new BatchItemRequest();
                                itm1BatchItem.bId = guid;
                                itm1BatchItem.Item = itm1;
                                itm1BatchItem.operation = OperationEnum.create;
                                itm1BatchItem.operationSpecified = true;
                                batchRequest.BatchItem[i] = itm1BatchItem;
                            }



                            //IntuitBatchResponse batchResponse = commonService.ExecuteBatch<IntuitBatchRequest>(batchRequest);
                            try
                            {
                                DelegateBatchCompleted delegateBatch = new DelegateBatchCompleted(commonService.ExecuteBatch<IntuitBatchRequest>);
                                IAsyncResult result = delegateBatch.BeginInvoke(batchRequest, new AsyncCallback(CallbackMethod), delegateBatch);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                throw ex;
                            }


                            break;

                        default:
                            throw new Exception("Data Source not defined.");
                    }


                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        private Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Item CreateItem(string str)
        {
            Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Item item = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Item();

            item.Desc = str + "Test Desc";
            item.Name = str + "Test Name";
            item.Taxable = true;
            item.TaxableSpecified = true;
            item.ExternalKey = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = str + "123" };
            item.UnitPrice = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Money() { Amount = 6, AmountSpecified = true, CurrencyCode = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.currencyCode.AED, CurrencyCodeSpecified = false };

            item.IncomeAccountRef = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountRef() { AccountId = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.IdType() { idDomain = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "1" }, AccountType = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.AccountTypeEnum.Asset, AccountTypeSpecified = true };

            item.Type = Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.ItemTypeEnum.Assembly;

            return item;
        }

        static void CallbackMethod(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            DelegateBatchCompleted delegateBatch = (DelegateBatchCompleted)result.AsyncState;
            IntuitBatchResponse batchResponse = delegateBatch.EndInvoke(result);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Batch Process QBO - To asynchronously access multiple data objects in a single request

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear: The Quickbooks API only allows one customer to be edited at a time.

They presumably lock the Customer table because concurrent edits are not supported by either the business layer or underlying data model.

Given this restriction, I don't see a way around the issue.

They allow you to call the synchronous method asynchronously so you do not have to block until the method completes, but that does not mean you can be in two customer edits at the same time.  You could however do other work while the edit completes.

Comment: so what is the meaning of batch process ?

Comment: Batch Process : To asynchronously access multiple data objects in a single request

Comment: Navneet, The SDK will allow you to batch multiple API calls together, but it still doesnt allow you to add/edit multiple names in the same call. I cant be sure what you are doing with out seeing the code. Did you follow the instructions for creating a listener? Are you able to make one or more calls in batch and get the callback event?